# GridView AutoPaging & List<Type>

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'have a list of element that is set as my gridview datasource. When I'm activating AutoPaging, my list can be load but if I click on a page number, __EVENTTARGET is null so this function doesn't work:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
```

However, if is set EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks to True, No data are being load !

Help me ! I'm becoming crazy !!

Comment: what about setting `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these two links, you may have to set the value of the _EVENTTARGET yourself in the event of changing pagination of the grid view.

1)[How the auto post back works](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/189-AutoPostBack-What-How-works.aspx)

2)[How to find which control caused auto post back](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/haissam/archive/2007/05/18/Which-Control-Caused-PostBack_2100_.aspx)

Hope it helps,

Cheers